# Different images inserted from Android into database shows same value?

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I am trying to insert image into SQL Server here is my code and it works perfectly (it inserts image into database). My problem starts after insertion and  when I see the image column in database.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        con = connectionClass(ConnectionClass.un, ConnectionClass.pass, ConnectionClass.db, ConnectionClass.ip);
        if (con == null) {
            z = "No Internet Connection";
        } else {

            String sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblComplaint] (customerName,type,image) VALUES ('" + name.getText() + "','" + complain.getText() + "','" +encodedImage+"')";
            //PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            //stmt.executeUpdate();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isSuccess = false;
        z = e.getMessage();
    }

    return z;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection connectionClass(String user, String password, String database, String server) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection = null;
    String connectionURL = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        connectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + "/" + database + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SQL Connection Error : ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return connection;
}
```

Problem: No matter what image I sent into database, it only inserts the same set of strings starting with: `0x2F396A2F34414151536B5A4A5267414241514141415141424141442F3467496F53554E44583142` and it goes on for a 100s lines, which I am guessing is not right. I have tried send 4-5 different images but this does not change. What am I doing wrong? Data type for image column is `image`, I have also tried `varbinary(max)` and so on.

Comment: You have to show us the code which writes to the database if you want help correcting it. Also you should not be using the `image` datatype anymore, only use `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: I have posted the code below but this is half of it , it wont let me paste all of the code , I coped it from DB , yes I have also tried VARBINARY but the result does not change.

Comment: Sorry yes , please see below

Comment: I think you would solve all your problems if you start using parameters instead of building a concatenated string for writing to the database. And if you did insist on using your existing code, you don't quote a varbinary value because its not a string.

Comment: Can you please provide me with an example ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with your technology, but the reference docs will show you the correct way to parameterise the statement.

Comment: `image` is not a data type that should be used in SQL Server any more, the documentation recommends `varbinary(max)` for new development and has done so since at least SQL Server 2005.

Comment: The strings are likely different. If you `select cast(0x2F396A2F34414151536B5A4A5267414241514141415141424141442F3467496F53554E44583142 as varchar);` for example you'd notice that the stored data is actually a base64 string. In other words you need to base64 decode it to retrieve the original binary data of the image file - which in this case is a JPEG image.

Comment: This is helpful thanks , I will try base64 decode

Comment: _Can you please provide me with an example_ In your previous question, you were parameterizing, though poorly because you should not use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning
This is how I am trying to decode it in ASP.net , its still not working. 

<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" ImageUrl ='<%# "data:Image/JPG;base64,"
                    + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("image")) %>'

Comment: Comments aren't a great place for large blocks of code - [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67464249/edit) your question if you want to add more code blocks for context.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to double-encode the image. Since it's already base64 encoded data that just happens to be stored in an `image` or `varbinary(max)` column you just need to append to `"data:image/jpeg;base64,"` with something like `Encoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])Eval("image"))` to let the browser deal with it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Encoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])Eval("image")) WORKED 
THANK YOU MUCH